# Extend text beyond limits of svg arc path?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have some labels arranged along the outside of a series of arcs (generated by pie charts). These labels are positioned along 'copies' of the pie arcs, which works to fit them nicely, but they unfortunately also cut them off prematurely, as seen in the screenshot below (in this case, an 'i' from the beginning and bracket contents at the end).

[image]

Is it possible to tell the text to extend beyond the path's limits? Or failing that, to extend the path itself along its existing course?

edit: The code I'm using to make the arcs is pretty much exactly what's found here: https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html.

Comment: Draw a longer invisible path and put the text on that.

Comment: @RobertLongson How do I extend the path I already have?

Comment: change the arc arguments, or whatever path command you're using to draw the arc.

Comment: There is an entire chapter on text elements in the svg1.2 spec; https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/flow.html You might find what you need there. That said I don't have a clue about browser support.